# How to access the email accounts in third party application in android?

Tags: java, android, email

I am creating an application to access a GMail account and some other EMail accounts that are not GMail. How can I access the inboxes of those email accounts my application?

Comment: am new to this concept,i don't know how to use.

Comment: Then go as far as you can. Write some pseudo code showing what data you need from GMail, write some real code using an imaginary function that you are missing, describe your use case, describe your environment ... The question in its current form has not enough information as it could be answered in a helpful manner without guessing.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer In my layout i have username and password edit-text field.When i give g-mail username and password.If its correct means to retrieve the all inbox values and show it in list-view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the following:

- You want to use Java.
- You are trying to retrieve a list of emails.
- You need to do this for GMail and non-GMail accounts.
- You didn't mention anything about persisting the mails on your device, so I assume you want a quick snapshot of the inbox.
- You didn't mention whether you want to leave the emails in the inbox or delete them upon retrieval, so you need a choice concerning that option.
- You have no knowledge how fetching EMails works technically.

So first you need to decide on how to access the mails. As you need to access GMail and non-GMail accounts, it seems that [accessing the mails via POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) would be a natural fit. "Usually" this access method will also delete the mails from the users inbox, but there is an option to download mails without deleting them. Authenticating via POP3 is handled in numerous ways, so I would go for a library that does this for you.

I am neither an Android Developer nor do I have much to do with Java outside of JSF, but the [Java Mail API](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/) seems to be capable of doing POP3 retrieval. And there is an [implementation for Android](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/).

Apart from that, your GUI **might** be missing a possibility to specify a server, a port and an option to pick the relevant encryption. You can of course "guess" these parameters from the given domain of the users email address, but you will need this information to retrieve the emails.

And of course you could also use [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol), which the Java Mail API also seems to be capable of.

Comment: Just out of interest: Do you want to delete the mails from the inbox when retrieving them?